# Migrating to Identity AspNetUsers

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I added `Identity` in my new MVC project, I have `DB` that have basic `Account`, `Customers` etc. tables that are used in WPF app. It all works now, registered users are added in `AspNetUsers` table... But my `DB` is useless.

Now I have 1000 Accounts with `Id` that is auto increment integer, `MobileNumber` and `Passwords`. How can I migrate all that in `AspNetUsers`, or better can I switch to my table and not use `AspNetUsers` table with String as Id because my other tables work with `Account` table?

Comment: account include the usernames and passwords as well?

Comment: Account have Mobile Number as Identity of Accounts, and passwords ofc. We didn't used Usernames and Emails, we're some sort of Car Wash. :)

Comment: ok. I was trying to understand if `Account` was your user base table of the past

Comment: Do you have any relational data thats constant in either table?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your's isn't a very general case, I don't see how Identity will have a direct solution. You can always use queries to migrate the data from `Account` to `AspNetUsers`. Mainly the `password` and `MobileNumber` (to `username`). Once moved, you can use `ApplicationUser` class to override any properties. I usually do something like this:

```
[MaxLength(36)]
public override string Id { get; set; }
```

Although the `Id` is still a string, it is a smaller string. If you really want to change this pk into a link, there is officially a long way provided https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-primary-key-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore2x

If you are worried about all your foreign keys being strings, a simple way would be to set up an in-between model something like this:

```
public class UserIdentity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

}
```

However, do keep in mind that this will have an additional join each time user details need to be verified.

**Update**

Considering that you already have a table `Account` with a primary key that is already used in other tables, you can also update your account `Account`.

```
public class Account 
{
    ...
    public int ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

This way you can continue to use `Account`'s fk

Comment: What to do with Id-s from Account table that are FK in many other tables? And what about adding new user, Id-s will be long string that Identity creates not auto increment Int?

Comment: if you want an auto-increment int, you need will need to follow the link and change the pk. you also have an option to make an additional unique key in `ApplicationUser` that you can use as FK and copy them from `Account` table via sql.

Comment: as of the first part of your question, I updated your question